# Puzzling Altium Violation (Beginner): Net Antennae

Tags: altium, via, ground-plane

I've recently run into a puzzling violation in Altium. My project has many issues admittedly, as you'll no doubt notice from the figures I've attached, but I'm trying to go one at a time here.

According to today's violation, I have somehow created a "Net Antennae" using a via that I thought I correctly routed to a ground plane Fig. 2 and 3

I have a four-layer PCB: Top(Signal), Inner1, Inner2, and Bottom(Signal). Inner1 represents a plane layer set to a net of +3.3V, and Inner2 represents another plane layer set as my Ground net. To clarify, by "set to a net" I mean I double-clicked on the layer in the bottom ribbon and set the layer to the corresponding net, Fig 1. It could be a rookie mistake which is why I'm starting with it, but I'm not sure if I'm supposed to be doing anything special other than that. As I understand it, a plane layer is just a flat sheet of copper so drawing a polygon on the inner layer would simply cut out a void which isn't what I imagine I would want.

Now, the definition of Net Antennae Tolerance states that it is "the maximum permissible length for the stub of an open-ended track/arc primitive (or one that terminates in a via)." However, I can't help but notice that I have another near identical via immediately to the left of the one in violation that somehow does not violate the current Net Antennae Tolerance rules.

If anything, the track to ground for the via in violation (59.362 mil) is shorter than its counterpart on the left (65.504 mil), see Fig. 4. I should note that the distance to the vias immediately below both the vias in question are identical, 19 mils from GND to 3V3 and 19 mil from GND to IO23, so I don't think that's the issue.

Any ideas for what is going on here? Is there something special I need to be doing to Inner2 so that Altium registers it as a copper ground layer?

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

[image: Figure 3]

[image: Figure 4]

[image: Figure 5]